# Custom Top Bar text possible without applet?

Tags: 20.04

In Ubuntu 20.04:
Want to insert some text about other software installed on platform.  Must I use an applet or is there a gnome setting somewhere to persistently have some 'xyzw' text in the top bar?

Thanks